# execute terminal command in isolated unix environment

Tags: linux, bash, web-applications, chroot, lxc

I am writing a webapplication in which users are able to execute git, bzr, and hg commands on the server.
Basically, a user writes the git/bzr/hg command into a html form, hits a button, the command is sent to the server, and executed in the directory the user owns.

How can I make this secure? I need to be able to execute a bash command which can only access and change one specific directory. And preferably, the directory in which the command is execute should not contain additional files. I think this is necessary for chroot.

Comment: ssh will help a lot but depends on your setup how easy will be to implement this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Chroot sounds like the way to go. If you can't use that, you must parse the command yourself and then rebuild a safe version before passing it on to the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always with user input, check it before passing it further to any command.

- Is it a valid git/bzr/hg subcommand
- Are there semicolons with additional unrelated commands
- ...

You can try running the commands in a restricted shell (`bash -r`), which prevents a few things.

The safer, though more complex, solution, is of course a `chroot` or even better a virtual machine.

Comment: lxc seems to be an alternative to chroot. Unfortunately, I was not able to implement my use case till now ...

Comment: `lxc` is basically a chroot extended to other areas as well.